# What's the best way to organise FlexUnit 4 tests in FlexBuilder 3?

Tags: apache-flex, unit-testing, flexunit4

I've recently started practising test driven development - thus far I've been working on a library project, so I've organised my FlexUnit tests in a separate FlexBuilder 3 project, linking against my library's swc.

Now I'm working on a web app and wondering how best to organise the tests for this.  At the moment I've put them in a src/test package in the project I'm testing, with the test runner application at the same level as the default application.  Is this the best way to do it, or should I have a separate test project and link in the source for the application I'm testing?  Or something different?

We don't automate tests at the moment, but this is something I would like to get working at some point, so a structure that would support that in the future would be helpful.

I've had a look at http://docs.flexunit.org/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_FlexUnit_4_Project but this (and the other docs here) explains well how to organise your tests, but doesn't advise on where to sit the tests in relation to the project I'm testing.

Thanks for any help,

cheers, Ange

Comment: +1 for a well placed question.  Best is often subjective. Flash Builder 4 has features to run tests directly from the same project, so that is probably the "preferred" method for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I think it's a matter of preferences. I like to have another Flex project that launches FlexUnit tests. So whether your project is a Flex project or a Library Project, you keep the same behaviour when launching tests.
Also, our CI build have it's own test launcher, so there was no need to have another one in our project.